# How to set an input's background transparency?

Tags: html, css

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

This fades both - input body and border. I don't want border transparent, just body, so the underlying image is visible. User-text inside the input should not be transparent, of course.

```
input [type="submit"]{
    margin-left:50px;  // here nothing works at all.
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be another way around this

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, I want to see parrent div, i.e. it's background image, and not overlapping them by form inputs. And also set the margins of `submit` button.

Comment: Either set `background:none transparent;` or create a 5x5 translucent .png and set that image as a repeated bg if you want it partially faded. That should be what you're after i believe?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question contents. Your are not setting any attribute values here.

Comment: …plus the JS is useless. I just did a `Ctrl + A` and `Ctrl + C` and have copied all the page contents. Also the context menu is still working for me since I've disabled the option to alter the right click menu via JS in my Opera installation. (While disabled is the default value in Opera for this option; see: http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/ at "Allow script to receive right clicks")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opacity` property influences the opacity of the whole element. Your question is bit vague, but I assume that you want to have a semi-transparent background, while the content and borders shouldn't have transparency.

To do so, you need to set a semi-transparent background to the element. This is called alpha-transparency, as a fourth color channel - the alpha channel - is used to store the transparency information (usually in an image like a PNG).

In modern browsers you could use the `rgba()` value for the `background` property:

```
/* semi-transparent white background */
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5 );
```

In MS IE you could use a gradient filter, which supports ARGB colors since MS IE 5. Just fade from a color to itself: (be aware, that the alpha channel comes first and all four color values are noted as two-digit hexadecimals)

```
/* the same for IE 7+8, should get included in a separate MS IE specific stylesheet */
background: none;
zoom: 1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=#E5FFFFFF, endColorstr=#E5FFFFFF );
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=#E5FFFFFF, endColorstr=#E5FFFFFF );
```

Comment: feeela, I see, I must run Photoshop :). Thanks a lot. I thought it is so simple, like any other css things.

Comment: feeela, maybe you should relax? :)

Comment: Yeah man, to me it was this:
"So what is your problem?"
But it's ok, you try to help and no feedback, I get you.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity works on the whole text input including the text inside it. So your code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Option **1**) Can you use **CSS3**? If so, use (with the color you want, of course):

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Option **2**) You can set the background of the Input as the **image** you want to see.

Option **3**) You can set the background as a **semi-transparent solid color image** (.gif/.png, which can be 1x1 in size and repeated in X and Y).

Comment: It seems that there is no way to see the underlying img through the inputs. Any color or another image will hide it. Semi transparent... I will try, but... ok, let's say - solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alegro You set a transparency to whatever you want – even to input's ;-)

Comment: I wonder why it's feeela's answer the right one if it has less content and was posted later... sigh.

Comment: @Ivozor And I wonder, if there is a right answer to that question. BTW: I am relaxed. I could only get stoned to be even more relaxed.

Comment: True that... Well, as long as it helped... :)

Answer (score 0):

For the submit, you need to [get rid of the space in your selector](http://jsfiddle.net/8qJjQ/):

```
input[type="submit"]{
  margin-left:50px; 
}​
```

And you can't specify what parts of the element you want to make transparent with `opacity`. It applies to err'thang. There might be 'hacks' of sorts to achieve what you want, such as using a wrapping div to create the border.

Comment: jmeas, code in your fiddle works, but in my file - not. What do you mean by - `get rid of the space in selector ?`

Comment: @jmeas You can set individual transparency to any CSS property that accepts a color value.

Comment: @feeela, you're absolutely right. I meant using the opacity property.